# How to find a book by category?

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have three classes:

BookController.java

```
@Controller
public class BookController {

@Autowired
private BookRepository book_repository;

@Autowired
private CategoryRepository category_repository;

@Autowired
private BookServiceImpl bookServiceImpl;

@RequestMapping(value = "/booklist")
public String bookList(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("books", book_repository.findAll());
    return "booklist";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/findbycategory")
public List<Book> findBookByCategory()..... (need to implement)

}
```

Book.java

```
@Entity
public class Book {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
private String title;
private String author;
private int year = 1600;
private String isbn;
private double price;

@ManyToOne
@JsonIgnore
@JoinColumn(name = "categoryId")
private Category category;

setters/getters/constructors...
}
```

Category.java

```
@Entity
public class Category {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long categoryId;
private String categoryName;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "category")
private List<Book> books;
...
}
```

BookRepository.java

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface BookRepository extends CrudRepository<Book, Long> {

List<Book> findByAuthor(@Param("author") String author);

List<Book> findByTitleLike(String title);
}
```

I want to write a method findBooksByCategory() which returns all books by category. I have OneToMany relationship between Category and Book. Category is as separate entity. I would know how to find book by lets say id (from Book.java) but I don't know how to behave when we have a class field as an instance of other object.

Comment: It'd be the same except passing a Category rather than a String.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Property Expressions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions)

There are multiple ways to achieve what you are trying to achieve. One of the possible ones will be;

```java
List<Book> findAllByCategory(Category category);
```

as suggested by @Compass

If you want to be more specific e.g. by category name, you can;

```java
List<Book> findAllByCategoryCategoryName(String categoryName);
```

or

```java
List<Book> findAllByCategory_CategoryName(String categoryName);
```

and then there is a native way to do this [assuming table names & columns];

```java
@Query(value="select b.* from book b inner join category c on b.category = c.id where c.name = ?1", nativeQuery=true)
List<Book> customQueryToFindListOfBooks(String categoryName);
```

Comment: Yes! It helps, but the biggest problem is that I do not know how BookController method should look like?

Comment: @GabrielėAgnėNormali Your controller method is an endpoint and can be of type accordingly. e.g. say, it's a `GET`, you can implement your controller method like; ```@RequestMapping(value="/bookByCategory/{categoryName}", method=GET) public List<Book> bookByCategory(@PathVariable("categoryName") String categoryName) {//implementation return YOUR_LIST_OF_BOOKS}```